# Google Services hogging data - how to stop it?

Tags: htc-desire-z, data-monitoring

**Note**: there is a [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26178/why-has-my-samsung-galaxy-s2-become-a-data-hog) to this, however it has no definitive answer.  Asking  in case anyone has discovered any solutions in the intervening period.

Onavo count continually reports that Google Services is hogging my data.  This seems a recent phenomenon - last few months or so.  I've switched off background sync and tried to restrict to wifi only.  All unsuccessful.  It continues to use

Phone is HTC desire Z running standard Android 2.3.3 (HTC Sense 2.1).

Phone was bought outright (i.e. not included as part of contract), running on SIM-only contract from O2 in UK.

Any suggestions for what's causing this?  And more pertinently, how to stop it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Google Services"? Please include more information.

Comment: @bigbadonk420: Onavo simply reports it as "Google Services".  It's listed under Settings->Applications->Running Services under the same name: contains 1 Service ("Google Messaging Service" and one process (com.google.process.gapps).

Comment: I guess OP means things like the GTalk service, which simply ignore sync/bgdata settings (and even "no network", as I saw in my logs just yesterday: GTalk reported an HTTP error when I was in Airplane mode for at least half an hour already, with even sync and data explicitly disabled).

Comment: Rather than creating a duplicate question, you should post a bounty on the original so that it gets more attention.

Comment: Related: [Why does "Google Services" take up increasing RAM and spawn new services over time?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9453)

Comment: Related (on a different site): [App Override Gives You Personalized Settings for Individual Apps](http://lifehacker.com/app-override-gives-you-personalized-settings-for-indivi-844552607). According to the description, you should be able to force apps to "wifi only", while others are still permitted to use mobile data. Amongst others, that is...

Answer (score 0):

Go To Settings> Accounts > Google > Click on Your Email/google account > Untick to disable any syncs that you don't need (eg: i dont need google play movies or bookmarks) > Turn off your device > take battery out > leave for 10 minutes > reconnect battery & turn on Your device > should be refreshed and ready to go with google services using less battery usage

Comment: I havent tried your answer. But as far i understand electronics, trying to turn on the phone without battery, would clear any energy left on it, not requiring waiting 10minutes.